# how to check NSString is a valid JSON string in iOS

Tags: ios, json

How to check if a `NSString` is a valid json string in iOS? Did oc have the api to check a nesting is a valid json string ?

Answer (score 3):

you can use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert NSString to Dictionary. If invalid json string format function will return error

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
if (error) {
    // handle error here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to `NSString` class is valid..

```
NSError *err;
id objJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[yourstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:&err];

if ([objJson isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
   // valid string
} else {
   // Not valid string
}
```